Sort overlay intersections by area of overlap
I am able to get list of attributes of overlapping geometries in QGIS . I want to sort by descending area of overlaps in the geometric .
Original Expression
array_to_string(overlay_intersects(
layer:='ahealth_geo_11ce95e5_8201_4bcd_bffd_b956d6aec640',
expression:="NAM_LABEL"
))

Currently failing expression
array_to_string(
    array_sort(
        array_foreach(
            overlay_intersects('ahealth_geo_11ce95e5_8201_4bcd_bffd_b956d6aec640', $geometry),
            area(intersection($geometry, @element))
        ),
        order_by:=@element DESC
    )
)

Error
syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting COMMA or ')'
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end of file

Incidentally, you experience the error in your expression because array_sort has no order_by parameter. ascending:=false would suffice. However, @spatialthoughts answer is a much more robust way of achieving your goal.

The overlay_intersects() function has an optional parameter sort_by_intersection_size that will sort the results by their overlap area. Check the documentation for usage instructions.

thank you . this is working  ---------                   array_to_string(
overlay_intersects(
layer:='ahealth_geo_7450fe21_bdde_4a5d_8f41_c2faa10283fd',
expression:= "NAME",
sort_by_intersection_size:='des'
)
)
